# php regex not working, works in c#

Tags: php

could someone tell me why this regex does not work in php, but the pattern works in c#?

I'm trying to replicate a **working** function that i have in c# and i tried to use the same regex pattern that i used there, it does not return any results, i checked google and understand that php regex uses a different set of delimiters but now i have no idea why it won't work.

php:

```
$results_q = "#(?m)/watch-.*?title=#";
preg_match($results_q, $html, $results, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

working in c#:

```
var results = Regex.Matches(test, "(?m)/watch-.*?title=");
```

how can i make it work in php? what are the differences in the pattern?

regex subject:

```
<a href="/watch-2742524-Thor-The-Dark-World" title="Watch Thor The Dark World (2013)">
```

output should be: `/watch-2742524-Thor-The-Dark-World`

This is my php function and it's currently working but only returning one result, i expect alot! as the page has several items on it matching my pattern.

```
function parseURL($url, $page, $featured = false) {

    $opts = array(
        'http'=>array(
                'method'=>"GET",
                'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n"
                )
            );

    $context = stream_context_create($opts);

    $html = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);   
    $results_q = "/(?m)watch-.*?title=/";

    preg_match($results_q, $html, $results);    


    echo var_dump($results);

}
```

Comment: Please post what you expect the pattern to match, and what input strings you have tested which don't match.

Comment: sure see edit, i've tested "#(?m)//watch-.*?title=#" and "/(?m)/watch-.*?title=/" with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using wrong flag (last parameter of preg_match), http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php here as You can see this one PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE is allowed. You can just omit this last param

```
preg_match($results_q, $html, $results);
```

also i have modified a little bit you pattern , the rusult:

```
$html = "<a href=\"/watch-2742524-Thor-The-Dark-World\" title=\"Watch Thor The Dark World (2013)\">";
$html .= "<a href=\"/watch-asdf742524-Thor-The-Dark-World\" title=\"Watch Thor The Dark World (2013)\">";

$results_q = "#(?m)(/watch-[^\"]*).*?title=#i";
$res = preg_match_all($results_q, $html, $results);
var_dump($results);
```

Comment: Use [`preg_match_all()`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) if you expect multiple matches.

Comment: changed to preg_match_all

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

Keep it simple, the \s* is there due to unseen whitespace that may be there, also tried to avoid case sensitivity and stuff...

$results_q = "#href="(/watch.*)"\s*title#Uisx";

preg_match($results_q, $html, $results);

But was just a quicky try on my mobile...

Check this two websites

[php preg_matc](https://www.php.net/preg_match)

[php regex tester](http://www.phpliveregex.com/)